# Python encryption program (ECC)

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to code an encryption program that will encode a user's Inputed - if that's a word - string. The encryption method is just a basic use of an elliptic curve encryption and I am currently working on the encryption part of the program at the moment before I work on the mathematical, inverse modules etc. Etc. Required for public and private key calculations. Currently I am using the key `pub = 5` and a `max` value (derived from the product of 2 random primes) of `91`. This is all the information needed and the word I am testing the encryption on is 'happy'.

So far here is the code.

```
word = 'happy'
pub = 5
m = 91

for i in range(pub):
    if i == 0:
        word = word

    else:
        word = output

    for x in word:
        a = [(((ord(z)*ord(z))+1)/m) for z in word]
        b = [chr(i) for i in a]
        c = [str(i) for i in b]
        d = ''.join([str(i) for i in c])
        output = d
```

What I am trying to do is encrypt each letter by multiplying the ASCII value it belongs too by itself and then use the `chr()` function to rejoin the string after a process of adding `1` then dividing by `m` , thus creating a new word. Then, using that new string, set it as the value of `word` for the next cycle in the loop, so the process continues until it has finished pub amount of times and encrypted the word. I'm having a lot of difficulties with this and I don't know where to start with explaining the issues. I'm relatively new to Python and any suggestions and/or advice on completing this fast would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I run this the output is "chr() arg not in range(256)"

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your math is right. Your formula (z**2 + 1)/m grows quadratically. My understanding of crypto is quite limited, but it doesn't look right to me. It should be some kind of one-to-one mapping from input to output. But it maps several neighboring characters to the same output. Also, the results grow with every round.

You can only convert the integers back to ascii characters for a range up to 256. That's what your error message says. It's proably thrown in the second iteration of your outer for loop.
You probably need to get the value range down to 256 again.
I suppose you miss a crucial part off the algorithm you are trying to implement, maybe some modulo operation.

Also some minor python hints:

You can use the built in power operator **, so you don't have to evaluate ord() twice.

```
((ord(z) ** 2) + 1) / m
```

You can do the conversion back to the string in one step like this:

```
output = ''.join([str(chr(i)) for i in a])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, each loop the large numbers need to be 'wrapped' around the max value but i have absolutely no idea how to code it. On paper i can do this process but in codeits difficult